# Make a table from a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list

```
  mylist<-list( "[3] C(+57.02)", c("[11] C(+57.02)", "[16] C(+57.02)"), "[3] C(+57.02)",c ("[5] M(+15.99)", "[6] M(+15.99)"))
```

I would like to get a table like this where the name is the object list number.

```
      1               2                   2                 3                   
"[3] C(+57.02)" , "[11] C(+57.02)", "[16] C(+57.02)", "[3] C(+57.02)",  
      4               4
"[5] M(+15.99)", "[6] M(+15.99)"
```

I tried to do this but it not exactly what I am looking for.

```
table(unlist(mylist))

[11] C(+57.02) [16] C(+57.02)  [3] C(+57.02)  [5] M(+15.99)  [6] M(+15.99) 

         1              1              2              1              1
```

Comment: `data.frame(unlist(mylist))` or maybe the traspose `t(data.frame(unlist(mylist)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rep` + `seq_along` + `lengths` + `setNames`:

```
setNames(unlist(mylist), rep(seq_along(mylist), lengths(mylist)))
##                1                2                2                3                4                4 
##  "[3] C(+57.02)" "[11] C(+57.02)" "[16] C(+57.02)"  "[3] C(+57.02)"  "[5] M(+15.99)"  "[6] M(+15.99)"
```

---

A nicer presentation might be to use `stack`:

```
stack(setNames(mylist, seq_along(mylist)))
##           values ind
## 1  [3] C(+57.02)   1
## 2 [11] C(+57.02)   2
## 3 [16] C(+57.02)   2
## 4  [3] C(+57.02)   3
## 5  [5] M(+15.99)   4
## 6  [6] M(+15.99)   4
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a named character vector. Don't get why you want a `table` here.

Data:

```
mylist<-list( "[3] C(+57.02)", c("[11] C(+57.02)", "[16] C(+57.02)"), "[3] C(+57.02)",c ("[5] M(+15.99)", "[6] M(+15.99)"))
```

Code:

```
v <- unlist(mylist)
names(v) <- rapply(mylist,length) %>% rep(seq_along(mylist),.)
```

Output:

```
> v
               1                2                2                3                4                4 
 "[3] C(+57.02)" "[11] C(+57.02)" "[16] C(+57.02)"  "[3] C(+57.02)"  "[5] M(+15.99)"  "[6] M(+15.99)" 
>
```